# unexpected bootstrap 3 behavior in fiddle

Tags: twitter-bootstrap-3

bootstrap 3 in included in the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sangramfuture/jC7af/2/) the following html

```
<div class="col-lg-1">hi</div>
<div class="col-lg-10">hi</div>
<div class="col-lg-1">hi</div>
```

has expected output:-

```
hi          hi                                                  hi
```

where as in the fiddle it shows as: -

```
hi
hi
hi
```

Why is that?

Comment: Show us your whole code. Did you add a container?

Comment: for the moment i'm just talking about the code in the fiddle. The problem i think ( i may be wrong) is that when you use the grid system and change the screen size, the width: field of .col- does not show anymore. ( i hope i am able to put my point across). In short i'm just talking about the code in the fiddle.

Comment: I'm not sure if I did understand you correct but yes, if you make your width too small it will move the divs under each other.

Comment: why is the fiddle out put different from expected output?

Comment: my issue, is that i'm using a similar structure of .col-lg-s. the screen shows expected output. but when i magnify the screen of the browser, as some users do. each of the divs becomes of 100% width and stack one below the other.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

bootstrap 3 is mobile first. Which means the screen size is very important to bootstrap. The screen size be default in the fiddle is very small.

.col-lg- is being used which is for large screen sizes. substituting it with .col-xs you get expected output

```
<div class="col-xs-1">hi</div>
<div class="col-xs-10">hi</div>
<div class="col-xs-1">hi</div>
```

[updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sangramfuture/jC7af/4/)